# Пересланное сообщение с тремя картинками через апи обрабатываются как 3 разных сообщения. Как это исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Пересылаю сообщение с тремя картинками боту в телеграмме. Боту через апи приходит 3 сообщения. Первое - с текстом и одной картинкой, второе и третье - по 1 картинке. Можно ли как-то объеденить эти сообщения в одно? Щас у меня бот обрабатывает каждое сообщение отдельно из-за этой штуки. Мне нужно, чтобы обрабатывалось толтко один раз.

```
{'message_id': 5063, 'from': {'id': 898800120, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Гоголь', 'last_name': 'Саша', 'username': 'dariuz', 'language_code': 'en'}, 'chat': {'id': 898800120, 'first_name': 'Гоголь', 'last_name': 'Саша', 'username': 'dariuz', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1659032061, 'forward_from_chat': {'id': -1001416287398, 'title': 'Борус', 'username': 'borusio', 'type': 'channel'}, 'forward_from_message_id': 33435, 'forward_date': 1658975566, 'media_group_id': '13272256490664514', 'photo': [{'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAITx2Li0f2xw6Hgks7cqqRBxG22mIG1AAJ7vzEbF44QS28oaUQPd6eqAQADAgADcwADKQQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADe78xGxeOEEt4', 'file_size': 1385, 'width': 90, 'height': 67}, {'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAITx2Li0f2xw6Hgks7cqqRBxG22mIG1AAJ7vzEbF44QS28oaUQPd6eqAQADAgADbQADKQQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADe78xGxeOEEty', 'file_size': 27546, 'width': 320, 'height': 240}, {'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAITx2Li0f2xw6Hgks7cqqRBxG22mIG1AAJ7vzEbF44QS28oaUQPd6eqAQADAgADeQADKQQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADe78xGxeOEEt-', 'file_size': 150091, 'width': 1024, 'height': 768}, {'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAITx2Li0f2xw6Hgks7cqqRBxG22mIG1AAJ7vzEbF44QS28oaUQPd6eqAQADAgADeAADKQQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADe78xGxeOEEt9', 'file_size': 155368, 'width': 800, 'height': 600}], 'caption': 'Два человека погибли в ДТП в Казачинском районе края после столкновения легковушки и автобуса\n\nПо предварительной информации ГИБДД, сегодня около 7:00 на 189 километре трассы Красноярск-Енисейск водитель Toyota Ractis выехал на встречную полосу и столкнулся с  пассажирским автобусом.\n\nВ результате столкновения водитель и пассажир Toyota погибли на месте. В автобусе находилось 14 пассажиров, 8 из них обратились к врачам с травмами.\n\n@borusio', 'caption_entities': [{'offset': 436, 'length': 8, 'type': 'mention'}]}
{'message_id': 5064, 'from': {'id': 898800120, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Гоголь', 'last_name': 'Саша', 'username': 'dariuz', 'language_code': 'en'}, 'chat': {'id': 898800120, 'first_name': 'Гоголь', 'last_name': 'Саша', 'username': 'dariuz', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1659032061, 'forward_from_chat': {'id': -1001416287398, 'title': 'Борус', 'username': 'borusio', 'type': 'channel'}, 'forward_from_message_id': 33436, 'forward_date': 1658975566, 'media_group_id': '13272256490664514', 'photo': [{'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAITyGLi0f2if-XgD88XHoiM55FAY7AcAAJ8vzEbF44QS9MviDXN7is7AQADAgADcwADKQQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADfL8xGxeOEEt4', 'file_size': 1199, 'width': 90, 'height': 67}, {'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAITyGLi0f2if-XgD88XHoiM55FAY7AcAAJ8vzEbF44QS9MviDXN7is7AQADAgADbQADKQQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADfL8xGxeOEEty', 'file_size': 20305, 'width': 320, 'height': 240}, {'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAITyGLi0f2if-XgD88XHoiM55FAY7AcAAJ8vzEbF44QS9MviDXN7is7AQADAgADeQADKQQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADfL8xGxeOEEt-', 'file_size': 107032, 'width': 1024, 'height': 768}, {'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAITyGLi0f2if-XgD88XHoiM55FAY7AcAAJ8vzEbF44QS9MviDXN7is7AQADAgADeAADKQQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADfL8xGxeOEEt9', 'file_size': 112815, 'width': 800, 'height': 600}]}
{'message_id': 5065, 'from': {'id': 898800120, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Гоголь', 'last_name': 'Саша', 'username': 'dariuz', 'language_code': 'en'}, 'chat': {'id': 898800120, 'first_name': 'Гоголь', 'last_name': 'Саша', 'username': 'dariuz', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1659032061, 'forward_from_chat': {'id': -1001416287398, 'title': 'Борус', 'username': 'borusio', 'type': 'channel'}, 'forward_from_message_id': 33437, 'forward_date': 1658975566, 'media_group_id': '13272256490664514', 'photo': [{'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAITyWLi0f0KE8r2rkCnd8XyvyZqjCfdAAJ9vzEbF44QS1eZi2aXXBNAAQADAgADcwADKQQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADfb8xGxeOEEt4', 'file_size': 1220, 'width': 90, 'height': 67}, {'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAITyWLi0f0KE8r2rkCnd8XyvyZqjCfdAAJ9vzEbF44QS1eZi2aXXBNAAQADAgADbQADKQQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADfb8xGxeOEEty', 'file_size': 20584, 'width': 320, 'height': 240}, {'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAITyWLi0f0KE8r2rkCnd8XyvyZqjCfdAAJ9vzEbF44QS1eZi2aXXBNAAQADAgADeQADKQQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADfb8xGxeOEEt-', 'file_size': 107729, 'width': 1024, 'height': 768}, {'file_id': 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAITyWLi0f0KE8r2rkCnd8XyvyZqjCfdAAJ9vzEbF44QS1eZi2aXXBNAAQADAgADeAADKQQ', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADfb8xGxeOEEt9', 'file_size': 113574, 'width': 800, 'height': 600}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Это логика бота. Просто работайте с тремя сообщениями. Обратите внимание, что передаётся параметр media_group_id у всех трёх сообщений.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]